# Каков механизм добавления элементов в ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

Как этот процесс устроен внутри `ArrayList`? Хотелось бы узнать подробности реализации. Как оно значениями оперирует? В частности - что и как делает метод `grow()`.

Comment: Что это было? Сначала вопрос и тут же в секунду секунду ответ на свой вопрос?

Comment: @BarmaleysupportsMonica Это был самоответ в целях аккумуляции знаний на ruSO.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Сначала разберемся, какими способами можно увеличить ArrayList.

1) с помощью метода `add(T element)`
2) с помощью метода `add(int index, T element)`
3) с помощью метода `addAll(Collection<? extends T> c)`
4) с помощью метода `addAll(int index, Collection<? extends T> c)`

Разберем каждый из способов отдельно:

1) Вот исходный код метода `add(T element)`:

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    modCount++;
    add(e, elementData, size);
    return true;
}
```

Он увеличивает переменную `modCount`(количество структурных преобразований). Вот выдержка из javadoc 1.4:

> Это поле используется iteratorом и выполняет реализацию iteratorа, возвращаемого методами iteratorа и listIterator. Если значение этого поля неожиданно изменяется, iterator (или iterator списка) будет вызывать исключение ConcurrentModificationException в ответ на следующие действия: удаление, предыдущее, задание или добавление. Это обеспечивает отказоустойчивое поведение, а не недетерминированное поведение перед лицом одновременной модификации во время итерации.

Затем вызывает метод `add(E e, Object[], int s)`. А после возвращает true, так как он должен это значение возвращать, так как так указано в `Collection.add(E e)`.

Разберем этот метод `add(E e, Object[] elementData, int s)`. Вот исходный код:

```
private void add(E e, Object[] elementData, int s) {
    if (s == elementData.length)
        elementData = grow();
    elementData[s] = e;
    size = s + 1;
}
```

В переменной `e` - наш создаваемый элемент. В переменной `elementData` - массив всех элементов(может быть не полностью заполнен), и `s` - количество реально располагающихся в массиве элементов элементов. Если массив заполнится не полностью - добавляем элемент в массив и увеличиваем переменную, содержащую количество реально располагающихся элементов. Иначе - помимо этого предварительно увеличиваем размер массива с помощью метода `grow()`.

Разберем этот метод `grow()`. Вот исходный код:

```
private Object[] grow() {
    return grow(size + 1);
}
```

Значит, он лишь вызывает другой метод grow, но уже с параметром `int minCapacity`, в который мы помещаем значение переменной, содержащей количество реально располагающихся элементов, увеличенное на единицу. Вот и его исходный код:

```
private Object[] grow(int minCapacity) {
    int oldCapacity = elementData.length;
    if (oldCapacity > 0 || elementData != DEFAULTCAPACITY_EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA) {
        int newCapacity = ArraysSupport.newLength(oldCapacity,
                minCapacity - oldCapacity, /* minimum growth */
                oldCapacity >> 1           /* preferred growth */);
        return elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, newCapacity);
    } else {
        return elementData = new Object[Math.max(DEFAULT_CAPACITY, minCapacity)];
    }
}
```

Если массив не пуст, то мы увеличиваем наш исходный массив на длину, равную половине(округление вниз) старой длины, если получившаяся длина не больше максимальной длины массива(`Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8`), иначе равную максимальной длине массива, если `oldLength + minGrowth` меньше максимальной длины массива, иначе равную `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.
Иначе мы заново инициализируем массив, передавая в него ссылку на массив объектов длиной 10 или `minCapacity`, если `minCapacity` > 10.
Если кого интересует код `ArraysSupport.newLength`, вот исходники([из java 13 только нашел](https://java-browser.yawk.at/java/13/java.base/jdk/internal/util/ArraysSupport.java#jdk.internal.util.ArraysSupport%23MAX_ARRAY_LENGTH)):

```
public static int newLength(int oldLength, int minGrowth, int prefGrowth) {
    // assert oldLength >= 0
    // assert minGrowth > 0

    int newLength = Math.max(minGrowth, prefGrowth) + oldLength;
    if (newLength - MAX_ARRAY_LENGTH <= 0) {
        return newLength;
    }
    return hugeLength(oldLength, minGrowth);
}

private static int hugeLength(int oldLength, int minGrowth) {
    int minLength = oldLength + minGrowth;
    if (minLength < 0) { // overflow
        throw new OutOfMemoryError("Required array length too large");
    }
    if (minLength <= MAX_ARRAY_LENGTH) {
        return MAX_ARRAY_LENGTH;
    }
    return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

Разбор метода `add(T element)` окончен.

2) Вот исходный код метода `add(int index, T element)`:

```
public void add(int index, E element) {
    rangeCheckForAdd(index);
    modCount++;
    final int s;
    Object[] elementData;
    if ((s = size) == (elementData = this.elementData).length)
        elementData = grow();
    System.arraycopy(elementData, index,
                     elementData, index + 1,
                     s - index);
    elementData[index] = element;
    size = s + 1;
}
```

`rangeCheckForAdd(int index)` кидает ошибку, если `index` не входит в число реальных элементов. modCount традиционно увеличивается. Затем увеличиваем длину массива с помощью метода `grow()`, если места для нового элемента нет, и сдвигаем все элементы, находящиеся справа от индекса, куда нужно вставить элемент, вправо, вставляя в образовавшееся "пустое пространство" объект, который нужно вставить. Внутренняя переменная длины традиционно увеличивается.

3) Вот исходный код метода `addAll(Collection<? extends T> c)`:

```
public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    Object[] a = c.toArray();
    modCount++;
    int numNew = a.length;
    if (numNew == 0)
        return false;
    Object[] elementData;
    final int s;
    if (numNew > (elementData = this.elementData).length - (s = size))
        elementData = grow(s + numNew);
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, elementData, s, numNew);
    size = s + numNew;
    return true;
}
```

`modCount` традиционно увеличивается. Получаем массив из коллекции, чтобы можно было совершить вставку массива с помощью стандартного метода. Если коллекция, которую необходимо вставить, пуста, то возвращаем `false`. Если вставляемая коллекция не вмещается в массив - увеличиваем его. Затем добавляем "коллекцию" в самый конец массива. Внутренняя переменная длины традиционно увеличивается. Рапортуем о удачном выполнении работы.

4) Вот исходный код метода `addAll(int index, Collection<? extends T> c)`:

```
public boolean addAll(int index, Collection<? extends E> c) {
    rangeCheckForAdd(index);

    Object[] a = c.toArray();
    modCount++;
    int numNew = a.length;
    if (numNew == 0)
        return false;
    Object[] elementData;
    final int s;
    if (numNew > (elementData = this.elementData).length - (s = size))
        elementData = grow(s + numNew);

    int numMoved = s - index;
    if (numMoved > 0)
        System.arraycopy(elementData, index,
                         elementData, index + numNew,
                         numMoved);
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, elementData, index, numNew);
    size = s + numNew;
    return true;
}
```

`rangeCheckForAdd(int index)` выполняет ту же функцию, что и при вставке одиночного элемента. Выполняем все то же, что и в `addAll(Collection<? extends T> c)`, до строчки с созданием переменной `numMoved`, в которую записывается количество реальных элементов массива, следующих после `index` включительно(помните, что итерация начинается с 0!). Если они вообще есть, то перемещаем их направо, освобождая место для вставляемой коллекции. Затем производится вставка коллекции в диапазон, начинающийся с `index`. Внутренняя переменная длины традиционно увеличивается. Рапортуем о удачном выполнении работы.

Спасибо за внимание. Если заметили ошибку или неточность - скажите о ней, готов принять любую критику.

Comment: Это конечно все прекрасно, однако я плохо понимаю где тут полезная информация. Тут нет никаких выводов. Как из вышеописанного сделать какие-либо выводы?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ А зачем? Задача то в пояснении механизма добавления элементов в ArrayList. Выводов быть и не должно. Суть как раз и состоит в разъяснении.