# Объект существует пока есть ссылка?

Tags: java

По-моему, одно из первых, чему учат java-новичков, это то, что объект существует, пока существует ссылочная переменная указывающая на него. А потом придет сборщик мусора и т.д.
Тогда почему работает подобный код? Ведь ссылок нет. Как живут объекты new Cat()?

```
static class Cat{}

List<Cat> list = new ArrayList<>(10);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    list.add(new Cat());
}
for (Cat cat : list) {
    System.out.println(cat);
}
```

Comment: А в list что находится?

Comment: @Эникейщик будем говорить, ячейка массива внутри list служит ссылкой на объект new Cat()? Вы об этом?

Comment: @GrossmasteR Посмотрите устройство метода add(). Здесь я подробно его разбирал: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1060744/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-arraylist/1060745#1060745

Comment: @GrossmasteR, если вы можете получить доступ к объекту (например, достав его из списка, или из какого-то другого объекта), значит на него есть ссылка. Когда ссылки нет - например, если вы создали объект, сразу передали его в `println`: `System.out.println(new Cat());`. Такой объект после того как отработает `println` будет удален сборщиком мусора.

Comment: Правда если вы не знаете как получить доступ к объекту еще не означает что на объект нет ссылок. В предыдущем примере `println` мог бы сохранять все переданные ему объекты в какое-то статическое поле, тогда бы объекты также не были удалены сборщиком мусора.

Answer (score 0):

Оператор `new` создает экземпляр указанного класса и возвращает ссылку на вновь созданный объект.
Т.е. когды Вы пишете строку `list.add(new Cat());`, вы добавляете в `list` ссылку на новый объект класса `Cat`.

А в строке `for (Cat cat : list)` идёт считывание по очереди ссылок на объекты из списка `list` во временный объект `cat`

А объект действительно существует, только пока существует ссылочная переменная указывающая на него. Т.е. если выполнить `list.remove(0);`, то ссылка на нулевой элемент списка будет утеряна, и можно будет сказать, что этот нулевой объект перестанет существовать.

Comment: `идёт считывание по очереди ссылок на объекты из списка`, не из списка, а из внутреннего массива указанного списка.

Comment: джавадоки гласят о том, что `ArrayList` - это реализация изменяемого массива интерфейса `List`. Из-за чего его можно назвать и массивом, и списком